# Arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Errors are like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "NearestCentroid.py", line 53, in <module>
    clf.fit(X_train.todense(),y_train)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scikit_learn-0.13.1-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/sklearn/neighbors/nearest_centroid.py", line 115, in fit
    variance = np.array(np.power(X - self.centroids_[y], 2))
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

Codes are like this:

```
distancemetric=['euclidean','l2']
for mtrc in distancemetric:
for shrkthrshld in [None]:
#shrkthrshld=0
#while (shrkthrshld <=1.0):
    clf = NearestCentroid(metric=mtrc,shrink_threshold=shrkthrshld)
    clf.fit(X_train.todense(),y_train)
    y_predicted = clf.predict(X_test.todense())
```

I am using `scikit-learn` package, `X-train`, `y_train` are in LIBSVM format, `X` is the feature:value pair, `y_train` is the target/label, `X_train` is in CSR matric format, the `shrink_threshold` does not support CSR sparse matrix, so I add `.todense()` to `X_train`, then I got this error, could anyone help me fix this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the value of `y_train` ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I had a similar problem using the Pystruct `pystruct.learners.OneSlackSSVM`.

It occured because my training labels were floats, in stead of integers. In my case, it was because I initialized the labels with np.ones, without specifying dtype=np.int8. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 7):

It happens quite often that an indexing array should be clearly `integer` type by the way it is created, but in the case of empty list passed, becomes default `float`, a case which might not be considered by the programmer. For example:

```
>>> np.array(xrange(1))
>>> array([0])                #integer type as expected
>>> np.array(xrange(0))
>>> array([], dtype=float64)  #does not generalize to the empty list
```

Therefore, one should always explicitely define the `dtype` in the array constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes your data is in integer and every thing is right but it happened because one of your data series is an empty array, so you can use this condition:

```
if len(X_train.todense())> 0:
```

Comment: Empty arrays don't throw an error - they just return an emptry array