# For-Loop over python float array

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I am working with the IRIS dataset. I have two sets of data, (1 training set) (2 test set). Now I want to calculate the euclidean distance between every test set row and the train set rows. However, I only want to include the first 4 points of the row.

A working example would be:

```
dist = np.linalg.norm(inner1test[0][0:4]-inner1train[0][0:4])
print(dist)
***output: 3.034243***
```

The problem is that I have 120 training set points and 30 test set points - so i would have to do 2700 operations manually, thus I thought about iterating through with a for-loop. Unfortunately, every of my attemps is failing.

This would be my best attempt, which shows the error message

```
for i in inner1test:
    for number in inner1train: 
        dist = np.linalg.norm(inner1test[i][0:4]-inner1train[number][0:4])
        print(dist)
```

> (IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean)
> type)

What would be the best solution to iterate through this array?

ps: I will also provide a screenshot for better vizualisation.

[image: visualization]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, `inner1test` is a tuple of lists, so the `i` value will not be an index but the actual list.

You should use enumerate, which returns two variables, the index and the actual data.

```
for i, value in enumerate(inner1test):
    for j, number in enumerate(inner1train): 
        dist = np.linalg.norm(inner1test[i][0:4]-inner1train[number][0:4])
        print(dist)
```

Also, if your lists begin the be bigger, consider using a generator which will execute your calculcations iteration per iteration and return only one value at a time, avoiding to return a big chunk of results which would occupy a lot of memory.

eg:

```
def my_calculatiuon(inner1test, inner1train):
    for i, value in enumerate(inner1test):
        for j, number in enumerate(inner1train): 
            dist = np.linalg.norm(inner1test[i][0:4]-inner1train[number][0:4])
            yield dist

for i in my_calculatiuon(inner1test, inner1train):
   print(i)
```

You might also want to investigate python list comprehension which is sometimes more elegant way to handle for loops with lists.

[EDIT]

Here's a probably easier solution anyway, without the need of indexes, which won't fail to enumerate a numpy object:

```
for testvalue in inner1test:
    for testtrain in inner1train:
        dist = np.linalg.norm(testvalue[0:4]-testtrain[0:4])
```

[/EDIT]

Comment: Unfortunately, it still shows the same error, even if I enumerate it. 
The inner1test in a numpy.ndarray. I saw a post where they elaborated on that error, I think it might be true for this specific case- but i am not sure how to implement it. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393989/arrays-used-as-indices-must-be-of-integer-or-boolean-type

Do you think this might be the solution?

Comment: Just added an easier example which does not need any indices

Comment: Thanks. However, the edit is not really iterating over the two arrays. It must iterate, as the output should be the full array of 2700 distances. Or am I mistaken and did not implement your solution the correct way?

Comment: Hmmm... You should write a `for i in inner1test: print(i)` and the same for inner1train to make sure your variables are iterable. If not, post the results please.

Answer (score 1):

This was the final solution with the correct output for me:

```
distanceslist = list()

for testvalue in inner1test:
    for testtrain in inner1train:
        dist = np.linalg.norm(testvalue[0:4]-testtrain[0:4])
        distances = (dist, testtrain[0:4])
        distanceslist.append(distances)
        
distanceslist
```

Comment: Happy to know you sorted it out